# DataTable Infinite scrolling unscrolled rows not available in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, datatables

I create a dataTable with infinite scrolling as

```
$('#table1').dataTable({
    'aaData' : dataArr,
    'aoColumns': columnArr,
    'bScrollInfinite': true,
    'bColumnCollapse': true,
    'sScrollY': '200px',
    'iDisplayLength': 20,
    'bAutoWidth': false
});
```

Now when this is loaded, it has message  `"Showing 1 - 20 of 1000"`.

In the chrome inspector, I can see only 20 rows in the table. Rest become available only after scrolling to the bottom of table, the other rows appear in DOM.

Is there a way we can make all the rows appear in DOM without srolling?

Comment: The entire point of the infinite scrolling is to avoid loading 1000 rows unless the user scrolls to them. You can't really create 1000 DOM rows without loading the data for them, which defeats the purpose of infinite scrolling.

Comment: My aim is to add rows to the bottom of the table (having infinite scroll) and perform DOM manipulations on them. With the above scenario I cannot access the bottom rows unless the user manually scrolls to the bottom of the table. Is there a way I can auto scroll to the bottom of the table?

Comment: If you need to manipulate them, why didn't you just load them initially (by loading more than 20 rows)?

Comment: I want to display just 20 rows in the UI but need to find some way for dataTable to scroll to the bottom row automatically.

Answer (score 0):

http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options

add another property called :

```
'iDisplayLength ' : 1000
```

not sure what will display all results for you when results will be more than 1000, but you can try passing 0 or -1, it should probably work.
if not, just insert int.max value.

Comment: But this will display all 1000 rows. That will defeat the purpose of infinite scrolling. Is there a way I can make dataTable to scroll to the bottom rows automatically?

Comment: i have a question, why not order descending ? it will be way more user friendly than scrolling 1000 rows